# add marker with Google-Maps-for-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

I was playing with https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails and
i'd like to clear all the marker on a map and add a new one at the position clicked by the user on the map, I added the following code in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function gmaps4rails_callback() {
   google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.map, 'click', function(object){ 
      alert(object.latLng);
   });
</script>
```

And in this way i can see an alert with the lat and long value, now how can i delete the old markers and create a new marker and place it on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clear markers created by `gmaps4rails`, use this js function:

```
Gmaps4Rails.clear_markers();
```

otherwise, loop through your markers and make `marker.setMap(null)`

Well, the following function removes all markers and add a new one where user clicks:

```
var marker = null;
function gmaps4rails_callback() {
   Gmaps4Rails.clear_markers();
   if (marker != null) { marker.setMap(null); }
   google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.map, 'click', function(object){ marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: object.latLng, map: Gmaps4Rails.map});});
}
```

Notes:

- You could use whatever logic you desire in the js code to create only one marker or send it's coordinates through ajax.
- latitude can be retrieved with: `object.latLng.lat()`, longitude with: `object.latLng.lng()`

Another way to add markers is to use the `add_marker` function described here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Dynamic-%28or-Ajax%29-map-refresh

Comment: thanks it works. do you know if there is a way to remove also the merker just added from your function? I have to get this behaivor: show markes on the map[OK], remove all the markers on the map[OK], click on the map and I add a marker[OK], ckick again on the map and remove the previous marker and show the new one. thx

Comment: The link in @apneadiving's response (https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Dynamic-%28or-Ajax%29-map-refresh) seems to go to a empty wiki page now.

Comment: @Nick: see here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies