# Accessing the Google map object via Gmaps4Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am successfully using GMaps4Rails to render markers from a Rails/Mongoid/Spacial model, and I am generally finding GMaps4Rails just unbelievably cool.

However, one thing keeps nagging in the back of my mind (although I got it to work OK): in all examples and answers I've seen the Google map object accessed through `Gmaps4Rails.map`, e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.map, 'click', function(object){ 
  alert(object.latLng);
});
```

(Taken from [add marker with Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596996/add-marker-with-google-maps-for-rails))

However, I never got this to work. If I log the `Gmaps4Rails.map` object to the console, it is undefined. The `Gmaps.map` object is of type `Gmaps4RailsGoogle`, so to get to the actual Google map, I need to write e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.map, 'click', ...)
```

I am instantiating the map via

```
 = gmaps(:map_options => {"detect_location" => true, "center_on_user" => true, 
   "zoom" => 12})
```

Any hints would be much appreciated, as I have a nagging feeling that I am doing something incorrectly.

**Update**: I should have read https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/From-0.x.x-to-1.x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any question here :)

Since my 1.0.0 release, some things have changed, so yes you're finding dated indications. But you've found the answer using `Gmaps.map.map`.

Here:

- `Gmaps` is a namespace containing all the maps you could create ion your page
- all maps containers are found by id and default id is `map` (I like short expressions)
- to get the map object from the map container, you append another `.map` (this is a bit annoying but I kept this to avoid users to become mad)

But all details for migration from 0.x.x to 1.x.x can [be found here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/From-0.x.x-to-1.x.x) (there are few).

Comment: Ahh, so the prevailing intertubes-based documentation was wrong and I was in fact on the right track :) Many thanks to apneadiving for making me sleep much better.